# Android Facebook integration user revoke permissions handling

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am working on integrating our company's android application with facebook login via facebook sdk. I am able now to communicate with facebook to get an access token but I have a problem that raises two questions:
1- the specific one is: what to do if the user revokes the facebook application from his account in 'apps' tab?
2- the more general: how to handle permissions change in my application if the user change them in his account?

Comment: And what problem are you facing while doing this manually?

Comment: Plz mention your approach

Comment: I get a message in fb login dialog: error validating access token. the use has not authorized application {app_id}